# How can we perform a "natural sort" using usort function

Tags: php, sorting

How can we perform a "natural sort" (as done by function `natsort`) using `usort`  function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: I know how to use `usort` it doesn't does a natural sort  like this.